# Ruby attr_reader allows one to modify string variable if using <<

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

Ran into some weird behaviour and wondering if anyone else can confirm what I am seeing.

Suppose you create a class with a member variable, and allow it to be read with attr_reader.

```
class TestClass
  attr_reader :val

  def initialize(value)
   @val = value
  end
end
```

Now when I do the following, it seems to modify the value of @val, even though I have only granted it read privileges.

```
test = TestClass.new('hello')
puts test.val
test.val << ' world'
puts test.val
```

This returns

```
hello
hello world
```

This is just the result from some testing I did in irb so not sure if this is always the case

Comment: `attr_reader` means that you can't set the value, i.e., no method `value=` is defined.  It certainly doesn't mean that you can't cal a method on the object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not really writing the val attribute. You are reading it and invoking a method on it (the '<<' method).

If you want an accessor that prevents the kind of modification you describe then you might want to implement a method that returns a copy of @val instead of using attr_reader.

Comment: Rather than implementing another method, you could also duplicate and freeze the value in `initialize`. I.e., `@val = value.dup.freeze`. (If you know `value` is a string, you can accomplish the same thing with `@val = -value`)

Answer (score 4):

Just a little modification of your example:

```
test = TestClass.new([])
```

Now you should get (replace puts with p to get the internal view):

```
[]
['hello']
```

It's the same thing. You 'read' val, and now you can do something with it. In my example, you add something into the Array, in your example you add something to your String.

Read-access reads the object (which can be modified), write-access change the attribute (it replaces it).

Perhaps you look for `freeze`:

```
class TestClass
  attr_reader :val

  def initialize(value)
   @val = value
   @val.freeze
  end
end

test = TestClass.new('hello')
puts test.val
test.val << ' world'
puts test.val
```

This ends in:

```
__temp.rb:12:in `<main>': can't modify frozen string (RuntimeError)
hello
```

To avoid side effect with a frozen variable, you may duplicate `value`:

```
class TestClass
  attr_reader :val

  def initialize(value)
   @val = value.dup.freeze  #dup to avoid to freeze the variable "value"
  end
end

hello = 'hello'
test = TestClass.new(hello)
puts test.val

hello << ' world' #this is possible
puts test.val  #this value is unchanged


test.val << ' world' #this is not possible
puts test.val
```

Comment: Be careful with this. You'll want to duplicate the value, so you don't end up freezing somebody else's variable that they passed in.

Comment: @JayMitchellI extended my answer to catch this side effect. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

Assigning is different to modifying, and variables are different to objects.

```
test.val = "hello world"
```

would be a case of *assignment* to the `@val` *instance variable* (which would not work), whereas

```
test.val << " world"
```

would be a *modification* of the *object* referred to by `@val`.

[Why does the absence of the assignment operator permit me to modify a Ruby constant with no compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670094/why-does-the-absence-of-the-assignment-operator-permit-me-to-modify-a-ruby-const) is a similar question, but talking about constants rather than instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

While this *seems* unexpected, this is exactly right. Let me explain.

The `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` class macro methods define "getter" and "setter" methods for instance variables.

Without a "getter" method, you don't have access to an object's instance variables simply because you're not in the context of that object. The "setter" method is essentially this:

```
def variable=(value)
  @variable = value
end
```

Since the instance variable points to a mutable object with a set of methods itself, if you "get" it and manipulate it, it stands to reason that those changes will take. You do not need to use the above setter method to call `variable.<<(value)`.