# Ruby: class attr_reader for an array is able to give write access to array values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, setter, getter

Is this the way that **attr_reader** is supposed to work with **arrays** ?

```
class User
  def initialize
    @interests = []
  end
  attr_reader :interests
end

u = User.new

=> #User:0x1d2cb60

u.interests << "music"

=> ["music"]

u.interests[1] = "travelling"

=> ["travelling"]

u.interests = nil

NoMethodError: undefined method `interests=' for u:User
```

I am just checking if my own explanation is correct, if not please correct me:

Is attr_reader not stopping me from assigning "@interests" values because you are not directly modifying the instance variable itself (which still holds a reference to the array object) but you are just operating on the values that that array object references ?

If that's correct, is there a quick and nice way to avoid attr_reader giving me write access to the array values, but letting me read them ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby attr\_reader allows one to modify string variable if using <<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002279/ruby-attr-reader-allows-one-to-modify-string-variable-if-using)

Comment: Yes indeed the questions are on exactly the same topic but I'd like to point out that mine is a bit different in the fact that other than reporting the behaviour I am also explicitly asking for ways to modify it.. also I found it a bit hard to find the correct wording to look for other answers about this, but.. up to you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is correct with regards to "not directly modifying the instance variable".  @interests is unchanged, however since it's a mutable object, the caller can sneak in behind you.

If you want to disallow edits of the :interests field, just `freeze` it.  The timing is tricky since you want to prevent writes before handing the object back to the user, so you'd probably need to do this at object creation time:

```
def initialize(whatever)
   @foo = bar
   @interests = %w(a b c).freeze
end
```

Just be careful should your object want to make changes to @interests.  You'd need to rebuild the array entirely, since you cannot unfreeze an object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll wait a bit more to see if other answers are coming, and if not I'll flag it right.
..So I'd need to do data serialization because #dup will not deep copy it... right? deep copying on objects would have made for a nice new little feature for Ruby 2.0 :) oh well..

Comment: Correct, you generally want to write your own #dup methods if you're going to be doing that a lot.  OTOH, this is a rare case where you can reuse the same object since it's frozen - ergo nobody can change it!  :)  And if you write your own #dup you can take advantage of that fact... but better write a comment to save yourself a headache down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Code your own getter, and use dup to supply a copy of the original array:

```
def interests
  @interests.dup
end
```

Full code:

```
class User
  def initialize
    @interests = []
  end

  def interests
    @interests.dup #
  end
end

# Without dup:
u.interests # => []
u.interests << "music"
u.interests # => ["music"]

# With dup:
u.interests # => []
u.interests << "music"
u.interests # => []
```

(Naturally, you'd need a slightly more advanced solution for multidimensional arrays and similar layered data structures)

Comment: Welcome to SO :)